# Move to a brand new Hyper-V Cluster

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, failover, shared-storage

We have a 2 node Hyper-V cluster with DAS storage, both nodes running 2012R2.

We are going to add two brand new nodes into the existing cluster - both running 2012R2. This will have its own DAS Array connected only to these new nodes.

We aim to decommission the original two nodes and the storage attached.

Can you storage migrate VMs from the current two nodes, across to the new nodes and their associated storage? Would this work directly migrating the VMs storage to storage or would we need to present both storage arrays to all nodes?

Comment: Short answer to both of your question - yes

Comment: Sorry - so the original DAS storage could be connected just to the original nodes, and the new storage, connected only to the new nodes, and storage migration would work?

Comment: You can change the datastorage for each VM, when you have added the storage to the cluster

Comment: But do all 4 nodes each need to be connected to both DAS arrays to achieve this?

Comment: Just one of them need to be connected to both. Then you have to do the migration from that machine

Comment: Hi just to clarify, as long as both sets of storage are seem by the failover cluster manager then there is no need to attach your new servers to both arrays,

Comment: You may also be using SCVMM that allows to move VMs between CSVs or any other storage available to the cluster.

Comment: I seem to be getting conflicting information :(

Comment: Hi PnP did you see the link in my Answer? also I have done this, storage migration does not need shared storage. you can move your VMs between the two storage arrays without all the nodes being connected to each array.

Answer (score 1):

Add your two new nodes to the cluster, configure their storage as a cluster shared volume (CSV) then perform storage migration:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2012/04/26/windows-server-2012-storage-migration-for-cluster-managed-virtual-machines/

The Article above is for server 2012 but it is relevant for server 2012R2 as well

Storage migration will migrate the VMs disks to your new DAS Array. it can do it live as well so no downtime!